# How align horizont of camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I make game in Unity3d. How align horizont of camera, when camera rotated.
Good horizont: http://prntscr.com/9hlirq
Horizont, which need align: http://prntscr.com/9hliyf

I try (but its not wrong):

```
var angles = transform.localEulerAngles;
transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, angles.y, 0);
```

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use localEulerAngles, they resulting rotation will always be relative to the object's parent.
You can use eulerAngles instead, which will set the rotation in world space:

```
var angles = transform.eulerAngles;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, angles.y, 0);
```

Rule of thumb: all members of Transform whose name starts with "local" are relative to the parent object (local space), and most of these members have a counterparts without the "local" prefix, working in world space.